# Why is the use of Raspbian (specifically Mathematica) on Orange Pi devices not illegal?

Tags: raspbian, wolfram-engine

I was seeing few YouTube videos in which people where demonstrating the installation procedure for modified Raspbian image on orange pi pc. I could also see the icons of pre-installed Mathematica on them (although I couldn't see them open it).

Now, from what I know Raspbian has a few licensed software packages such as Minecraft and Mathematica which are only allowed to run on a Raspberry Pi for non-commercial usage (which is the reason why Raspbian for PC and Mac doesn't have them). I wonder why usage of Raspbian and hence Mathematica on non-licensed devices is not questioned by anyone.

Is this legal? Or am I missing some agreements? I have an Orange Pi and would like to clear things up before I use Raspbian (although 2 years old and not updated) and hence Mathematica that comes pre-installed in it.

Comment: From the [License Agreement](https://wolfram.com/legal/agreements/wolfram-mathematica-raspberry-pi.html) it doesn't like it's strictly legal to install Raspbian with Mathematica on the Raspberry Pi 3 either.... Perhaps Wolfram should update their license agreement... in any case, if you are planning on using the no-cost version for a commercial application, you are definitely violating the EULA. ... I generally remove Mathematica packages and use the Free Software alternatives instead...

Comment: @RubberStamp No, not for commercial usage. Isn't it ambiguous in that(non-commercial) case too?. I wonder how can big companies like wolfram mess this up.

Comment: I don't think they are worried about numerous individuals trying out their software on low resource SBC boards... If you look through the Wolfram website, you'll notice that the Free Cost distributed version is basically a test run of their attempt to get into the IOT web programming space.  But if you are truly concerned, just remove the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not legal to use the Raspbian bundled Mathematica on anything but a Raspberry Pi.

> Permitted Uses and Installations
>
> Subject to the terms of this Agreement and Your acceptance thereof,
> WRI grants You a non-exclusive license to use the Product solely for
> personal or educational purposes on a Model A or Model B Raspberry Pi
> computer. You are also authorized to:

http://www.wolfram.com/legal/agreements/wolfram-mathematica-raspberry-pi.html

So there is no problem installing Raspbian as long as you don't **use** Mathematica.

Comment: What about the RPi3 ?  I think they need to update that agreement documentation.

Comment: @RubberStamp Not my problem.

Comment: @RubberStamp I suppose by "Raspberry Pi" they include all the versions of the device.

Comment: @paulplusx ... The agreement as written says, "Model A or Model B".  The Raspberry Pi 3 is neither of these.. nor is the Pi Zero either A or B.  Therefore, the downloaded image file available from raspbian.org is technically in violation of said agreement.  There should at least two versions of the image file to accommodate the Wolfram agreement. ... But, IANAL.

Comment: @RubberStamp it means it is not licensed for RPI0 and, possibly, the B+. Technically this is version 3 of the Raspberry Pi 3 model B, there hasn't been a new model A for a while. The "3" is the version/revision, the "B" is the model

Comment: @crasic ... point is OP has a point... the agreement language is obviously either old, or specifically limits the platforms... even among the various RPi flavors.

Comment: @RubberStamp Exactly! because the clones are modifying and indirectly commercializing raspbian.

Comment: @paulplusx ... but Raspberry Pi platform has now expanded beyond Model A and Model B... So, technically, what's the difference?  A Violation of the Agreement has occurred in either case.  But, the question should probably be answered by Wolfram directly instead of people posting on StackExchange.

Comment: @RubberStamp It seems they aren't stupid at all. I tried launching Mathematica in orange pi and the activation failed(due to some Wolfram kernel failure) . I guess I'll buy a pi just for Mathematica :-)

Comment: @RubberStamp It seems they aren't stupid at all. I tried launching Mathematica in orange pi and the activation failed(due to some Wolfram kernel failure) . I guess I'll buy a pi just for Mathematica :-) and put armbian on orange pi.

Comment: @paulplusx ... good test.  So, perhaps the OPs question is mute due to Wolfram checking processor and/or other hardware signatures before running.

Comment: @joan you might want to include the last two comments (one from my test and one from rubberstamp) in your answer :)

Comment: @RubberStamp Yes, I also remember seeing someone posting a similar error when they tried to use Mathematica(from raspbian) on a virtual machine.